# node.js fs.writeFile Not Completely Overwriting File

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

I have a file that is of length X and it is being overwritten by a string that is of length X-Y.  Problem is, that the file is still retaining the information past X-Y so that it is as long as the first longer file.  So here is my test output that is giving me fits:

File started as:

```
{
    "sOption1": "String",
    "nOption2": 23.5,
    "sOption3": "String",
    "bOption3B": true,
    "anOption4": [
        5,
        6,
        7
    ],
    "sNewString": "FruitSalad",
    "bNewBoolean": false,
    "iNewNumber": 14.2,
    "anNewArray": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
    ],
    "oNewObject": {
        "bToBeOrNotToBe": true,
        "sFinishQuote": "That is the question"
    }
}
```

Changed the data being written to the following:

```
{
    "sOption1": "String",
    "nOption2": 23.5,
    "sOption3": "String",
    "bOption3B": true,
    "anOption4": [
        5,
        6,
        7
    ],
    "sNewString": "YummyYummy",
    "bNewBoolean": true,
    "iNewNumber": 2.14,
    "anNewArray": [
        10,
        9
    ],
    "oNewObject": {
        "bToBeOrNotToBe": false,
        "sNewQuote": "To die, to sleep, no more"
    }
}
```

After this, the file is now:

```
{
    "sOption1": "String",
    "nOption2": 23.5,
    "sOption3": "String",
    "bOption3B": true,
    "anOption4": [
        5,
        6,
        7
    ],
    "sNewString": "YummyYummy",
    "bNewBoolean": true,
    "iNewNumber": 2.14,
    "anNewArray": [
        10,
        9
    ],
    "oNewObject": {
        "bToBeOrNotToBe": false,
        "sNewQuote": "To die, to sleep, no more"
    }
}       "bToBeOrNotToBe": true,
        "sFinishQuote": "That is the question"
    }
}}
```

See the garbage on the end of the object?  It's left over from the previous file, even though I wrote it out with the following code:

```
DeviceConfiguration.prototype.SetPersistentUserOption = function(sNewOptionName, NewOption)
{
    var sNewFile = "";
    var fs = require('fs');

    //if one of the primitive types, it's simple, just add it to object
    if(typeof(NewOption) == "string" || typeof(NewOption) == "number" || typeof(NewOption) == "boolean")
    {
        this.oPersistentUserOptions[sNewOptionName] = NewOption;
    }
    else if(NewOption instanceof Array)
    {
        //blank out array if it was there already
        this.oPersistentUserOptions[sNewOptionName] = [];   

        //now go back and copy each element over one at a time
        for(var nIndex = 0; nIndex < NewOption.length; nIndex++)
        {   this.oPersistentUserOptions[sNewOptionName][nIndex] = NewOption[nIndex];    }
    }
    else if(NewOption instanceof Object)
    {
        //blank out object if it was there already
        this.oPersistentUserOptions[sNewOptionName] = {};   

        //now go back and copy each element over one at a time
        for(Member in NewOption)
        {   this.oPersistentUserOptions[sNewOptionName][Member] = NewOption[Member];    
        }
    }

    //stringify the object, and make it pretty with options null, 4
    sNewFile = JSON.stringify(this.oPersistentUserOptions, null, 4);

    //write to the file, parameter is immediately in object memory though
    fs.writeFile(PERSISTENT_USER_SELECTED_OPTIONS_FILENAME, sNewFile, function(err){console.log(err);});
    //fs.writeFileSync(PERSISTENT_USER_SELECTED_OPTIONS_FILENAME, sNewFile);

    console.log(sNewFile.length);
    console.log(sNewFile);
};
```

I have checked to make sure that the sNewFile variable is the correct length, and it is. I also have paused as long as 6 seconds between subsequent writes out to disk, so I can't see how this could be a timing issue.

If I use writeFileSync the problem goes away, but I really don't have the option to do synchronous writes for this application as I'm timing critical and don't want to have to slow down to write to the disk.

I'm on node.js 0.8.21, but it doesn't look like the interface has changed any for fs between that and the up to date version.

Anyone else hit anything like this?  This is giving me fits. . .

Comment: What OS is this?  It sounds like it's defaulting to opening in `r+` mode, which wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: does my code work for you on ubuntu?

Comment: It does, just ran it.  I did a couple simple tests similar to that before posting and couldn't get it to fail.

Comment: test it on 0.10 or hack arround it by removing the file if it exists before you write the new contents.

Comment: I just updated question with the whole function that is doing writing.  I really don't want to update 0.10 right now.  Do you have any suggestions on how to remove the file before writing it out?  I tried hacking around by using fs.truncate, but I obviously am missing something in the documentation because I can't get it to quit crashing:  fs.truncate(PERSISTENT_USER_SELECTED_OPTIONS_FILENAME, 0, function(err){});

Comment: How are you reading the file to see what's in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just tested this on 0.8.21 ( linux ) and this works as expected.

```
var fs = require('fs')

var str1 = "aaaaaaaaaa"
var str2 = "bbbbbb"
var str3 = "bbbbbbaaaa"

fs.writeFile('test',str1,function(){
  fs.writeFile('test',str2,function(){
    fs.readFile('test','utf8',function(err,buff){
      console.log(buff === str2)
      console.log(buff === str3)
    })
  })
})

output
> node test.js
true
false
```

Comment: I just updated the question to show what I am writing out, that data is straight from the console right after the write call.

Comment: Found my problem, writeFile works just like it should.  Thanks so much for your help.  My problem was that in my upstream code, I was writing to the file 6 times in a row without pausing.  This caused a very repeatable race condition that looked like it wasn't timing.  I was looking in the wrong place.