# Node.js fs.writeFile() not ovewriting file

Tags: node.js

According to the docs the default behavior of `fs.writeFile` is to truncate the file if it already exists. It does not appear to be doing that for me, and it is observable with a very simple test case.

```
var fs = require('fs')

var str1 = "aaaaaaaaaa" // start with this string
var str2 = "bbbbbb" // replace it with this string
var str3 = "bbbbbbaaaa" // this is the string which appears with an append

fs.writeFile('test',str1,function(){
  fs.writeFile('test',str2,function(){
    fs.readFile('test','utf8',function(err,buff){
      console.log(buff === str2) // should be true
      console.log(buff === str3) // should be false
    })
  })
})
```

Expected output:

`true
false`

Actual output:

`false
true`

This is occurring on CentOS with node `v0.10.24`. The example I have gave was from another SO question, and the author of that answer states that his machine is giving him the exact opposite of the same block of code as my machine. [node.js fs.writeFile Not Completely Overwriting File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750490/node-js-fs-writefile-not-completely-overwriting-file).

Comment: For what is worth, the output was as expected (true/false) on Windows and Ubuntu (I am using an older version of Node, not sure if that matters)

Comment: Can you elaborate which version of node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a known bug in the Vagrant winnfs plugin. There is a filed issue relating to this problem already at https://bitbucket.org/jankowfsky/winnfsd/issue/7/winnfsd-doesnt-always-overwrite-files.